# Get onclick values from HTML table to input form JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have an HTML table which gets updated every 1 second through AJAX. AJAX gets data from external PHP file and echoes it. Here is the HTML table:

```
<div style='float: left;'>
<br><br>
<p style="padding-left:16px; font-size: 20px;">Amount(<?php echo $market; ?>) | Price(<?php echo $bm; ?>) &nbsp | Total(<?php echo $bm; ?>)</p>
<div class="panel-hello scrollbar" id="style-11">
    <div class="data-table">
        <table class="table table-hello table-bordered table-hover force-overflow" id="btcaddresses">
            <tbody style="border: 1px solid green; height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I have an form with three Inputs. The html table provides rows with 3 columns. Here is the form:

```
  <form name="yourform" method="post" action="btccpa.php" style="float:right;">
    <div id="log_err">
        <strong><?php if(isset($eroor)) { echo $eroor; } ?><?php if($au == 1) { echo 'Please log in to trade.';} ?></strong> 
    </div>  
    <p>
        <label style="float: left;">Price:</label>
        <input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="uprice" id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
        <label style="float: right;">: <?php echo $market; ?></label>
        <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="uam" id="box4" oninput="calculate()"><br>
        <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="utam" id="resul"><br>
        <label style="padding: 10px;">Total <?php echo $bm; ?>:</label>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="yourform" value="1">
            <br><br>
            <span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="ordersell" onclick="yourform.submit()">SELL</span>
        </td>
    </p>
</form>
```

I want the values in html table to passed to the form when clicked on. Here is the AJAX being used:

```
    function loadXMLD()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("btcaddresses").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; // your div
  }
}
  xmlhttp.open("GET","get/sellbtccpa.php",true); //your php file
 xmlhttp.send();
}
window.setInterval(function(){
 loadXMLD();
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: "// code for IE6, IE5" — Whhhyyy?! It is 2018!

Comment: if the table is updated each 1 second as soon as you click on it and you fill the form data will be outdated

Comment: @LelioFaieta It's Ok but how to do it!

Comment: No answers? I thought someone will be knowing

Answer (score -1):

```
        var table = document.getElementById("btcaddresses");
   var j;
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)

                table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                  var rownumber;
                  rownumber = $(this).closest("tr").index();
                  document.getElementById("box3").value= table.rows[rownumber].cells[0].innerHTML;
                   document.getElementById("box4").value= table.rows[rownumber].cells[1].innerHTML;
                   document.getElementById("resul").value= table.rows[rownumber].cells[2].innerHTML;


}}}
```

Try this. box3, box4 ,resul are your input ids. You need JQuery btw.

Comment: Whats the rows[rownumber]

Comment: row number of clicked cell